# Case() in Django return a Type error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to use a huge request to minimize the number of requests in my app.
In my database I have some cards, each card has multiple amounts link to it, and each amount is linked to a category.
I try to get the Sum of amounts for a category between 2 dates and the same thing for 2 previous dates (dates are in cards) compare them and get the percentage evolution.
Everything works fine for all cases but one: If my sum for a category is 0 for the previous period, I have an error "Divide by 0" when I try to calculate the evolution.

So I tried to get the evolution, only if the sum of the previous period is != 0, and return 'N/A' if = 0. For this I use Case(When()). But I have an error and I'm not sure to understand why.

Here my request:

```
        categories = Category.objects.filter(
            Q(amount__card__date__range=(
                start_day_compare,
                stop_day_compare
            )) | Q(amount__card__date__range=(
                previous_start_day_compare,
                previous_stop_day_compare
            ))
        ).annotate(
            evolution=Case(
                When(
                    Sum(
                        'amount__amount',
                        filter=Q(
                            amount__card__date__range=(
                                previous_start_day_compare,
                                previous_stop_day_compare
                            )
                        )
                    ) != 0,
                    then=Value(
                        (
                            (
                                Sum(
                                    'amount__amount',
                                    filter=Q(
                                        amount__card__date__range=(
                                            start_day_compare,
                                            stop_day_compare
                                        )
                                    )
                                ) - Sum(
                                    'amount__amount',
                                    filter=Q(
                                        amount__card__date__range=(
                                            previous_start_day_compare,
                                            previous_stop_day_compare
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                                ) * 100
                        ) / Sum(
                            'amount__amount',
                            filter=Q(
                                amount__card__date__range=(
                                    previous_start_day_compare,
                                    previous_stop_day_compare
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                default=Value('N/A'),
                output_field=CharField()
            )
        ).order_by(
            'order'
        )
```

And this is the error:

> **init**() takes either a Q object or lookups as keyword arguments

This error is raised when I use previous_stop_day_compare the last time.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

You have misplaced the arguments to `Case` and `When`.

**Solution**:

```
Case(
    When(
        Sum(
            'amount__amount',
            filter=Q(
                amount__card__date__range=(
                    previous_start_day_compare,
                    previous_stop_day_compare
                )
            )
        ) != 0, # `Sum` ends here
        then=Value(
            (
                (
                    Sum(
                        'amount__amount',
                        filter=Q(
                            amount__card__date__range=(
                                start_day_compare,
                                stop_day_compare
                            )
                        )
                    ) - Sum(
                        'amount__amount',
                        filter=Q(
                            amount__card__date__range=(
                                previous_start_day_compare,
                                previous_stop_day_compare
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ) * 100
            ) / Sum(
                'amount__amount',
                filter=Q(
                    amount__card__date__range=(
                        previous_start_day_compare,
                        previous_stop_day_compare
                    )
                )
            )
        ) # `Value` ends here
    ), # `When` ends here
    default=Value('N/A'),
    output_field=CharField()
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated my code on my original question, but nothing changes, I have the same error :s But now it's rasied at the line previous_stop_day_compare 
(the last time it's used)